# how to download latest version of android sdk without android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I don't need to android studio, i am developing my project in godot,  godot [docs](http://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/learning/workflow/export/exporting_for_android.html) 
refer to [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html) to download android sdk, but i did not find any windows executable for standalone sdk on that page.

Comment: there is a link in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47167769/hello-world-android-app-with-as-few-files-as-possible-no-ide-and-text-editor/47251607#47251607)

Comment: is this command line utility?

Comment: I suggest you read my answer it has important relevance to you. It is a slightly older SDK that means you can update SDK WITHOUT Android Studio. The newer SDK has updates INTEGRATED inside Android Studio, which is bad news for you ! The link is SDK ONLY (what you want) and external SDK update manager (deleted in latest version) along with other cool stuff (not limited to command line).

Answer (score 2):

in the official page of [android](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#downloads) this the sdk in optional downloads come in a zip just unzip them and in the options of androidstudio seleccionalos

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow and well done at reading the entire tour page. Hope you enjoy your experience. This is MAINLY a user moderated site, moderation starts with the community itself, but you can always escalate any problems ans concerns you have (flag). Good first answer, but it's mainly a link only answer (we try to avoid that), don't be afraid to explailn (even if it is in the link) so we don't have to hop around finding an answer. Enjoy gaining rep, badges and helping others. As you gain rep you can comment on Questions and Answers, with  more power comes more responsibility...